# make[1]: Command not found

Tags: gcc, makefile

I am getting below error while building some set of files. Would someone give some pointers on why do I get this error? Am I missing installation of some package?

Snippet of error log:

```
make[1]: MMD: Command not found
    CC         drivers/usb/usbhid.libc.o
make[1]: MMD: Command not found
    CC         drivers/usb/usbmsc.libc.o
make[1]: MMD: Command not found
    CC         drivers/hid.libc.o
make[1]: MMD: Command not found
    AR         build/libc.a
make[1]: invalidar: Command not found
Makefile.inc:89: recipe for target 'build/libc.a' failed
```

Snippet of my makefile:

```
# macro to define template macros that are used by use_template macro
define create_cc_template
# $1 obj class
# $2 source suffix (c, S)
# $3 additional compiler flags
# $4 additional dependencies
ifn$(EMPTY)def $(1)-objs_$(2)_template
de$(EMPTY)fine $(1)-objs_$(2)_template
$(obj)/$$(1).$(1).o: $$(1).$(2) $(obj)/libpayload-config.h $(4)
        @printf "    CC         $$$$(subst $$$$(obj)/,,$$$$(@))\n"
        $(CC) $(3) -MMD $$$$(CFLAGS) -c -o $$$$@ $$$$<
en$(EMPTY)def
end$(EMPTY)if
endef
```

Comment: _Am I missing installation of some package?_ - A C compiler, perhaps? ;-) It looks like $(CC) is expanded to an empty string. You could try running `make V=1` to verify this hypothesis. After that you are going to need to figure out _why_ it's empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me as if the `CC` variable is not defined to anything when you invoke this macro, and the third argument is empty.  This means that the recipe make internalizes after the `eval` is expanded is:

```
-MMD $$(CFLAGS)...
```

A quick fix is to escape the variable for `CC`:

```
$$(CC) $(3) -MMD ...
```

I think your expansion model for this is very odd, and probably incorrect in other ways.  But, without seeing how this macro is used it's hard to say.

One easy way to debug `eval` issues is to duplicate the context where the `eval` appears and replace the `eval` with the `info` function.  This will print exactly what `make` will parse, and it should be completely normal and understandable makefile syntax; e.g., change something like:

```
$(foreach X,$(STUFF),$(eval $(call FOO,$X)))
```

to:

```
$(foreach X,$(STUFF),$(info $(call FOO,$X)))
$(foreach X,$(STUFF),$(eval $(call FOO,$X)))
```